# Process payments between users

Tags: php, paypal, stripe-payments, payment, venmo

What's the best way to process payments between users directly in app?

User [A] should be able to send money to user [B] without putting the vendor [APP] in the middle of the transaction.

I think that the best solution is **Venmo SDK** but unfortunately in Italy it's not available yet.
Stripe/Paypal don't allow to execute payments between users unless they have a Stripe/PayPal Account, correct?

Comment: not sure why this question is considered  broad